# Is there some text mining&data analysis plugins similar to tidyverse package(R) in Android instead?

Tags: android, r, analytics, text-mining, jri

I would like to create an android application which can produce plots and stats related to the textual data.I want to perform the same "data analysis"/text processing which I am enabled to with tidyverse and the correlated packages in R.I know that in java there are JRI/REngine/JRIEngine packages to interface with R,but I don't know whether it's possible to use them in some way,to achieve this goal in android(i'm an absolute beginner).
I would love very much to find a solution and will appreciate your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You can check out these awsome library for graphs and charts.

**[1. MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)**

**[2. GraphView](https://github.com/appsthatmatter/GraphView)**

**[3. WilliamChart](https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart)**

Also check the [Android arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/40) for a variety of charting and graphing library.

Comment: Thank you!Now I know where to look for!Android arsenal seems the right place